# Trying to understand routing for Web API2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I am new to setting up Web API methods, so I'm sure that I am butchering the routing to my action methods.

I was reading that Web API2 has attribute routing so I created:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/mytest")]
public class MyTestController : ApiController
{
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public string GetJob(int id)
    {
        return String.Format("Job-{0}", id.ToString());
    }

    [Route("/NewJob/{xmlData:string}")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage NewData(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
          // Read in posted xml and do stuff
    }
}
```

In my WebApiConfig I have:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

Now the GetJob method works when I call it:

```
$.get('api/mytest/4')
```

However I do not know how to set the route for the NewData method.
When I add the route attribute (see above) I get a runtime error:

> The inline constraint resolver of type
>   'DefaultInlineConstraintResolver' was unable to resolve the following
>   inline constraint: 'string'.

Updated:
Changed route:

```
[Route("NewJob/{xmlData}")]
```

AJAX Call

```
$.post('api/mytest/NewJob/', xmlData)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error indicates, the `DefaultInlineConstraintResolver` that Web API ships with does not have an inline constraint called `string` and it is key sensitive and you need to remove any white spaces. The default supported ones are the following:

```
// Type-specific constraints
{ "bool", typeof(BoolRouteConstraint) },
{ "datetime", typeof(DateTimeRouteConstraint) },
{ "decimal", typeof(DecimalRouteConstraint) },
{ "double", typeof(DoubleRouteConstraint) },
{ "float", typeof(FloatRouteConstraint) },
{ "guid", typeof(GuidRouteConstraint) },
{ "int", typeof(IntRouteConstraint) },
{ "long", typeof(LongRouteConstraint) },

// Length constraints
{ "minlength", typeof(MinLengthRouteConstraint) },
{ "maxlength", typeof(MaxLengthRouteConstraint) },
{ "length", typeof(LengthRouteConstraint) },

// Min/Max value constraints
{ "min", typeof(MinRouteConstraint) },
{ "max", typeof(MaxRouteConstraint) },
{ "range", typeof(RangeRouteConstraint) },

// Regex-based constraints
{ "alpha", typeof(AlphaRouteConstraint) },
{ "regex", typeof(RegexRouteConstraint) }
```